# Enabling Offchain workers in a parachain

Tags: parachain, offchain-worker

I know the way to enable ocw in a solo chain is to edit the service.rs as per the documentation and it works perfectly. I have tried making equivalent changes to the service.rs in my parachain but offchain_workers function is never triggered. Can anyone tell me if there is a way to make it happen for a parachain because I can't quite figure out all the configuration changes that need to be done in this case ?

Comment: This post may help: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5726/offchain-worker-not-initializing-cumulus-parachain-template