# Offchain Worker Not Initializing - Cumulus Parachain Template

Tags: substrate-node-template, offchain-worker, cumulus, substrate-parachain-template

I am observing unexpected behavior with the Cumulus Parachain Template. Our pallet uses [off-chain workers](https://github.com/SequesterChain/pallets/tree/main/donations) (OCW), and the functionality successfully runs when we attach it to the Substrate Node Template.

However, when I add our pallet to the [Cumulus Parachain Template](https://github.com/SequesterChain/sequester-parachain-template) and follow the [Connect a Local Parachain guide](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-relay-and-parachains/connect-a-local-parachain/), the functionality that requires off-chain workers stops running completely.

Is there a reason that OCWs are not initializing on the Cumulus Parachain Template while they do run on the Node Template? Does the chainspec need to be altered in some way?

Comment: Can you try running your node with the flag: `--offchain-worker always` and let me know if it solves the issue.

Comment: @Bruno sadly this does not fix the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are most likely missing the offchain worker initialisation in the service.rs file, like this https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/150c6c9e66bd4e866cfd4704d4d2a16799edc2c0/node/src/service.rs#L205

Comment: This fixes it, thanks! Put up a [PR](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/pull/1860) to add this directly into the Parachain Template Node to prevent others from hitting a similar issue in the future.