# How to enable off-chain workers for parachain via command line?

Tags: parachain, substrate-parachain-template, offchain-worker, offchain

There is no any logs and off-chain workers does not work by default.
How to specify to enable workers for parachain via command?

Comment: This post may help: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5726/offchain-worker-not-initializing-cumulus-parachain-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the parachain node template from Cumulus?

According to the help text, it's only enabled for nodes that are authoring new blocks:

```sh
./target/release/parachain-template-node --help
```

```
  --offchain-worker <ENABLED>
      Should execute offchain workers on every block.
      
      By default it's only enabled for nodes that are authoring new blocks.
      
      [default: when-authority]

      Possible values:
      - always:
        Always have offchain worker enabled
      - never:
        Never enable the offchain worker
      - when-authority:
        Only enable the offchain worker when running as a validator (or collator, if this is a parachain node)
```

Looks like it is enabled here:

```rust
if parachain_config.offchain_worker.enabled {
    sc_service::build_offchain_workers(
        &parachain_config,
        task_manager.spawn_handle(),
        client.clone(),
        network.clone(),
    );
}
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/590387a01cea1027cffeb1d70af49b44bd64d1d7/parachain-template/node/src/service.rs#L188-L195

So try running your node with the `--offchain-worker always` flag.